# install SSL certificate in mobile device(IOS ,Android) and get the Thumbprint of the installed certificate in XAMARIN project

Tags: ssl, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

is there any way to install **SSL certificate** in mobile device(IOS ,Android) and get the **Thumbprint of the installed certificate** to verify at the time of API call using `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in the mobile application using xamarin. currently I hardcoded the thumbprint values in code side and validating it with the certificate thumbprint in ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Comment: If you are installing certs on the device, I would highly recommend using Android's `android:networkSecurityConfig` and create the xml file that pins your primary and backup secure domains, thus no additional coding is required. Unfortunately iOS does not have a matching feature, so you have to do it in code via `SecTrustCopyPublicKey` and comparing the result, but you can not do that on the root cert, only the entire chain. So if you are forcing the user to install a cert to start with, then on updates/revokes/etc.. they would need to install the updates cert(s) **and** an updated app.

Comment: Thank u sushil , can you please provide any site for reference or example.@SushiHangover